# python bytes object possibly evaluating data within the bytes object

Tags: python, dns, udp, hex

Lets say I have `st = b'\x01\x20'` which I understand is supposed to be `0x0120` which is `288` in base 10 decimal.

My problem is that when using PyCharm it tells me that `st: b'\x01 '` where there is a visible white space after `\x01`. Now, I can see that for some reason it's evaluating it as the white space character, when it should keep it as is right?

I also printed `st` and the results are just as mentioned before, `b'\x01 '`. I'm trying to build a DNS query using UDP, and this is the flag result of the message header, so I assume it shouldn't be allowed to send the white space in place of the actual `b'\x20'`.

I suppose what I'm trying to ask is why is this happening? Additionally, would it still work if I just build the query with the interpretation of `b'\x20'` as a white space?

I'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: A space *is* the actual character.  If you want to send `\x02` as a raw byte, it should work regardless of which way you write it.

Comment: @BrenBarn Okay, thank you. I'll try it out and see how it goes.